# Remover espaço de uma coluna no Opencart

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

Fiz um select na tabela `oc_product` `SELECT * FROM oc_product` na coluna `sku` precisava remover todos os espaços desses itens são mais de 2000 linhas com esse problema é possível remover isso dinamicamente segue uma imagem da coluna com `skus`[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi voce precisa deixar tudo sem espaços

Segue um exemplo de instrução SQL para remover esses espaços e deixar tudo junto.

```
SELECT REPLACE(sku, ' ', '' ) FROM oc_product;
```

Utilizando o comando **REPLACE** dessa maneira, todos os espaço dessa coluna serão 'removidos' na consulta

Comando para **UPDATE**:

*(Só rode esse comando caso realmente queira alterar os dados na base! Caso contrário use o comando anterior)*

```
UPDATE oc_product set sku = REPLACE(sku, ' ', '' )
```

Comment: è só colocar essa query do jeito que está que funciona certo ?

Comment: exato Kirito, nessa query ele vai substituir os espaços em branco na sua CONSULTA, caso queira realmente trocar no banco ai terá de ser realizado um UPDATE

Comment: Adicionei a sintaxe que seria  utilizada no UPDATE